# c# async await function call not working as expected

Tags: c#

I am working in c# winform application.

I have this action code on a button click event:

```
    private int liveRATE = 0;
    private async void GetLiveRate()
    {                        
        var productResponseInitialStep = await productClient.GetProductTickerAsync(Currency);
        if (productResponseInitialStep.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {                
            liveRATE = 100;
        }

        if (liveRATE > 0)
            SendInitialPO(liveRATE);        
    }
```

Which is working as expected. and SendInitialPO is working.

Now I am trying to push few lines to a function so I can reuse it without writing few lines again and again. But its not working as I expected which is the code never touching SendInitialPO(liveRATE);.

```
    private int liveRATE = 0;
    private async void GetLiveRate()
    {                                   
        GetLiveRate2(); 
        if (liveRATE > 0)
            SendInitialPO(liveRATE);        
    }       

    private async void GetLiveRate2()
    {            
        var productResponseInitialStep = await productClient.GetProductTickerAsync(Currency);                
        if (productResponseInitialStep.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            liveRATE = 100;
        }            
    }
```

I was reading about how aync and await works. but not sure how can I solve my issue. I have tried to add do while loop but no luck. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: await GetLiveRate();  more async Task GetLiveRate()

Comment: @brykneval But first they have to make it return a `Task`

Comment: You have 2 functions with the same signature?

Comment: If it's `async` you typically return `Task` instead of `void`. Also, you're not actually using `await` on anything in the first `GetLiveRate()`. Also, why do you have two functions with the same name?

Comment: Also declare liveRATE as `private volatile int`

Comment: You really need to read over [Async Await Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). For anyone  that has done so, `async void` screams out that it's an issue. And instead of storing your results in a variable, you should return them from your method. Use a more *functional* programming pattern instead of storing state in fields that doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private int liveRATE = 0;
private async Task GetLiveRate()
{                                   
    await GetLiveRateAsync(); 
    if (liveRATE > 0)
        SendInitialPO(liveRATE);        
}       

private async Task GetLiveRateAsync()
{            
    var productResponseInitialStep = await productClient.GetProductTickerAsync(Currency);                
    if (productResponseInitialStep.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        liveRATE = 100;
    }            
}
```

With some best practices I would recommend following code block:
(see the subtle change of return type and variable declarations)

```
private async Task GetLiveRate()
{                                   
    var liveRATE = await GetLiveRateAsync(); 
    if (liveRATE > 0)
        SendInitialPO(liveRATE);        
}       

private async Task<int> GetLiveRateAsync()
{            
    var productResponseInitialStep = await productClient.GetProductTickerAsync(Currency);                
    if (productResponseInitialStep.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
      return 100;

    return 0            
}
```

anyway, the main takeaway is: `async void` is okay for event handlers only. You should return a `Task` and calls `await` when required.

For more details please refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async#return-types).

> An async method can have the following return types:
>
> - `Task`
> - `Task<TResult>`
> - `void`, which should only be used for event handlers.
> - Starting with C# 7, any type that has an accessible `GetAwaiter` method. The `System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>` type is one
>     such implementation. It is available by adding the NuGet package
>     System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.

Comment: @user1747541 glad that helped you. See the updated answer to get an idea on better way to code that.